# iOS JavascriptCore: pass primitive boolean to js callback?

Tags: ios7, javascriptcore

Say I have a method that can be called from JS:

```
- (void)doStuffToArray:(NSArray *)array withCompletion:(JSValue *)completion
{
    // do things to array
    [completion callWithArguments:@[...]];
}
```

And in JS it would be called like so:

```
doStuffToArrayWithCompletion(array, function (success) {
    if (success) ....
});
```

How do I pass in a primitive boolean value via `callWithArguments`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap any primitive values in a NSNumber:

```
[completion callWithArguments:@[@(YES)]];
```